# Creating a rect for each tile in Pygame to make collisions

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to create a rect for each tile in Pygame in order to make collisions- so enabling me to walk on blocks when I jump and not being able to run through a block. My map is a 2D list and I render it on the screen using for loops. I need help with collisions and creating a rect for each tile- would I need to create a rect for the 2D list, I'm not sure.

each_block and next_row are passed in the parameter and both have a value of 0,0 in the while loop e.g. so `player1.level1(0,0)`

```
def level1(self,each_block,next_row): #ROWS  #MOVE DOWN TO THE NEXT ROW
        self.game_level = [['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'], #LOOKING AT THIS 2D LIST, THE DIMENSIONS ARE 10X10
              ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
              ['0','0','0','0','2','2','0','0','0','0'],
              ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
              ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],
              ['2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2','2'],
              ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1'],
              ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1'],
              ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1'],
              ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1']]
       
        next_row = 0
        for row in self.game_level: #LOOPS THROUGH EACH ROW
            each_block = 0
            for each_tile in row: #LOOPS THROUGH EVERY STRING IN THE ROW
                if each_tile == '1':
                    WINDOW.blit(self.dirt_image,(each_block * 70, next_row * 70))
                if each_tile == '2':
                    WINDOW.blit(self.grass_image,(each_block * 70, next_row * 70))
                each_block += 1
            next_row += 1
```

```
self.area1 = pygame.Rect(x,y,scale_width,scale_height) #This is my player rect which is in the constructor.
```

I was thinking of doing something like this, but I don't know if it is correct or complete. I think this is only for the jumping?

```
pr = self.area1
for t in tiles:
    # assume each tile has a rect associated
    # check is the player is within the bounds of tile.
    if pr.right > t.rect.left and pr.left < t.rect.right:
        # check if the player is above the tile and below the tile is velocity is applied
        if pr.bottom < t.rect.top and pr.bottom + player.velocity >= t.rect.top:
            player.velocity = 0
            pr.bottom = t.rect.top
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That's a lot of tiles & rects.  As an optimisation, you could add code to merge rectangular blocks of the same tile into a single rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this, is to make a rectangle for each tile as the `level1` like function iterates over all the tiles.  You know the cell-position of the tile in the map, so multiplying this by the tile dimensions gives the rectangle parameters:

```
`tile_rect = pygame.Rect( map_x * TILE_SIZE, map_y * TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE )`
```

The problem is that gives you a lot of rectangles.  It's better to only make rectangles for the types that can collide.  There's no point testing collisions with a tile that's part of the background art.

So define a set of "platform" tile types:

```
`PLATFORM_TYPES = '21'`
```

And then check the tile-type code is a member of of that before making the tile:

```
tile_rect_list = []
if ( each_tile in PLATFORM_TYPES ):
    # valid platform-making tile, create a rect
    tile_rect_list.append( pygame.Rect( map_x * TILE_SIZE, ... ) )
```

If the code has a rectangle for the player, a collision calculation is as simple as calling the rectangle collision function [pygame.Rect.colliderect()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect).  Which would look something like this:

```
tile_rect   = pygame.Rect( ... )
player_rect = pygame.Rect( player_x, player_y, player_width, player_height )

collides = player_rect.collide_rect( tile_rect )
```

Or if you have a list of tiles:

```
for tile_rect in tile_rect_list:
    if ( player_rect.collide_rect( tile_rect ) ):
        # Player has collided, do something about it here
```

PyGame Rectangles are a really useful module.   You don't need to write code to check all the coordinates and lengths yourself.

One further optimisation is to create rectangles that span the rows of same-type tiles.  So a block of `2`-typed tiles `22222` creates a single rectangle that's 5 * *tile_width* long.

*One way* of doing this, is that when iterating through the rows of tiles, remember the previous tile-type.  Then only output a rectangle when the tile-type changes to a new type.

[image: screen shot]

```
import pygame

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH      = 320
WINDOW_HEIGHT     = 320

BLACK    = (  0,   0,   0)
GREEN    = (  0, 255,   0)
RED      = (255,   0,   0)


class Level():
    TILE_SIZE      = 32    # size of tiles in pixels
    PLATFORM_TILES = '12'  # tile types the player can walk on

    def __init__( self ):
        self.game_level = ['0000000000', #DIMENSIONS 10X10
                           '1000000001',
                           '0000220000',
                           '0000000011',
                           '0000000000',
                           '2022220220',
                           '1111111111',
                           '1111111111',
                           '1111111111',
                           '1111111110']

        self.tile_rects = []   # holds all the tile rectangles

        # Create a 2D list of tile-rects to match the map.
        # Rects are horizontal blocks of same-tiles
        for row_y, row in enumerate( self.game_level ):
            prev_tile_type = '*' # no match
            platform_start = -1  # start column of platform
            rect_y = row_y * Level.TILE_SIZE
            last_column = len( row ) -1
            for col_x, tile_type in enumerate( row ):
                # Match same tiles to make a longer rect
                if ( platform_start != -1 and ( prev_tile_type != tile_type or col_x == last_column ) ):  # tile changed
                    # The tile-type has changed, or it's the row-end, make the rectangle
                    # Handle the special case of the last cell in the row
                    if ( col_x == last_column and prev_tile_type == tile_type ):
                        col_x += 1
                    width  = ( col_x - platform_start ) * Level.TILE_SIZE
                    rect_x = platform_start * Level.TILE_SIZE
                    if ( prev_tile_type in Level.PLATFORM_TILES ):
                        self.tile_rects.append( pygame.Rect( rect_x, rect_y, width, Level.TILE_SIZE ) )
                    prev_tile_type = '*'
                    platform_start = -1
                elif ( tile_type in Level.PLATFORM_TILES ):
                    # If it's the last block in the row, make a rectangle, as there's no "next" block
                    if ( col_x == len( row ) - 1 ):
                        rect_x = col_x * Level.TILE_SIZE
                        self.tile_rects.append( pygame.Rect( rect_x, rect_y, Level.TILE_SIZE, Level.TILE_SIZE ) )
                    elif ( prev_tile_type != tile_type ):
                        # start a new row-block for the found tile-type
                        platform_start = col_x
                        prev_tile_type = tile_type
                    
    def getPlatforms( self ):
        """ Get the list of platform-collision rects """
        return self.tile_rects


###
### MAIN
###

pygame.init()
window  = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), pygame.HWSURFACE )
pygame.display.set_caption("Tile Rects")
pygame.mixer.init()


level = Level()


# Main loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:
    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            running = False

    window.fill( BLACK )

    for platform_rect in level.getPlatforms():
        pygame.draw.rect( window, GREEN, platform_rect, 5 )
        #print( "RECT: %d,%d w=%d h=%d" % ( platform_rect.x, platform_rect.y, platform_rect.width, platform_rect.height ) )

    # Draw a grid for debugging sizes
    for y in range( 10 ):
        for x in range( 10 ):
            pygame.draw.rect( window, RED, [ x*Level.TILE_SIZE, y*Level.TILE_SIZE, Level.TILE_SIZE, Level.TILE_SIZE ], 1 ) 


    pygame.display.flip()

    # Clamp FPS
    clock.tick(3)   # slow update

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: tile_rect_list.append( pygame.Rect( map_x * TILE_SIZE, ... ) ) What do you mean by map_x? map_y? Thanks for the help as well.

Comment: Oh so the x an y in the for loop. In this case it would be each_block and next_row?

Comment: @Mr.Potato Yeah, it's the coordinates of the map tile, Vs the coordinates in pixels.  So `map_x` might be `3`, but to get pixel-position for the surface, it's multiplied by the tile-size: (3 * 32) = 96 pixels (assuming a 32-pixel tile).  Similarly when going from pixel-position back to map-position, one would divide by the tile-size.  E.g.: if your object is at `px`, `py` on-screen, to find the map-tile, that's `px // TILE_SIZE`, etc.   Of course if the map starts scrolling, you need to also need to account for the offset of the window "view" of the map.